# WAS is using Axis2 for Webservice client instead of JAXWS

Tags: websphere, jax-ws, apache-axis

we have to use a third party system which exposes SOAP Services. We developed and tested locally using JAXWS and Jetty. All is working fine. when the same is deployed with in WAS 7.0, it seems, it is using Axis2 library the same is throwing few errors.
Any help\idea on what configuration needs change to make our EAR to use JAXWS instead of Axis2?

Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Axis2 is the JAX-WS implementation used by WAS 7, and it'll be picked up for any JAX-WS operations run on the server by default.

If your application is dependent on your own JAX-WS provider, as it sounds like you are, the procedure for using third-party web services engines is documented at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html

I happened to find the 8.5.5 document first, but the procedure is applicable to version 7 as well.